# Binary operations on a decimal input

Tags: c

I'm creating a binary calculator in C for a school project and I'm having trouble getting the right answer.

The assignment specificies that I can only read and print unsigned integer from the user and i cant use looping, so I created a variable that converts the binary input into decimal and then I apply the operator on those decimal numbers.

Code:

```
case 1:
        printf_s("Input a binary number and decimal shifting in the following format: 8-bit dec\n");
        scanf_s("%u %u", &b1, &b2);
        /*conversion of binary to decimal*/
        result1 = (b1 % 10) + (b1 / 10 % 10) * 2 + (b1 / 100 % 10) * 4 + (b1 / 1000 % 10) * 8 + (b1 / 10000 % 10) * 16 + (b1 / 100000 % 10) * 32 + (b1 / 1000000 % 10) * 64 + (b1 / 10000000 % 10) * 128;

        printf_s("\nThe result is %u\n", result1 << b2);
        break;
```

The problem I have is when I enter for example `00111100` and `3`, the program apparently doesn't know what to do the with the extra `1` and I get a wrong answer.

Comment: You need to learn the concept of looping and apply it to your case.

Comment: i cant use looping, the asigment only allows if/else and switch

Comment: loop, create a result, with every loop do "something" to the result. Ex. 25 in string is 2*10 + 5, and 253 is 25*10 + 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have various weird restrictions on what you "can" use, which makes this a guessing contest.

Anyway, to limit your decimal number to a certain number of digits, you can use modulo:

```
b1 %= 100000000;
```

This will remove any part exceeding 10,000,000, limiting it to 8 decimal digits which you can then interpret as binary bits.

Answer (score 0):

These artificial requirements serve no other purpose but to teach you bad habits. In a real-world application, you would read the input as a string, which would the most convenient and safe format. Then use loops or `strtol`.

That being said, you could read the unsigned integer as hex, which doesn't contradict the requirements. It would make the task slightly less absurd. Then mask each digit of the hex and translate to actual binary.

```
// don't write code like this in the real world
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint32_t wannabe_binary;
uint32_t actual_binary = 0;
uint32_t shift;

printf("Input a binary number and decimal shifting in the following format: 8-bit dec\n");
scanf("%"SCNx32 "%"SCNd32, &wannabe_binary, &shift);

actual_binary += (wannabe_binary & 0x10000000) ? 1<<7 : 0;
actual_binary += (wannabe_binary & 0x01000000) ? 1<<6 : 0;
actual_binary += (wannabe_binary & 0x00100000) ? 1<<5 : 0;
actual_binary += (wannabe_binary & 0x00010000) ? 1<<4 : 0;
actual_binary += (wannabe_binary & 0x00001000) ? 1<<3 : 0;
actual_binary += (wannabe_binary & 0x00000100) ? 1<<2 : 0;
actual_binary += (wannabe_binary & 0x00000010) ? 1<<1 : 0;
actual_binary += (wannabe_binary & 0x00000001) ? 1<<0 : 0;
```